# How to return element name using $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following HTML elements and I want to get some elements name using $(this) by clicking somewhere else in those HTML element.

HTML Code:

```
<span class="iselect dropdown">
    <ul class="ioptionlist">
        <li class="ioption">aa<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">bb<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">cc<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">dd<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">ee<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">ff<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
        <li class="ioption">gg<span class="iclosebtn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" class="iselectinput" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;" onClick="insertitag();"><img src="" width="32px" height="32px">cc</a>
    </div>
</span>
```

If I click dropdown-item and i want to access ul in above using $(this).

```
$(document).on('click', ".iselect .dropdown-menu a", function() {
---------Code----
});
```

Also I want to know when text box keyup I want to access dropdown-menu using $(this).

```
$(".iselect input").on("keyup", function(){
-----Code---
});
```

Reason why using $(this) method I have lot of this HTML code thesefor when I click it other HTML code Ul also access.

Comment: $(this).parent()

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all your selectors are wrong where is (a) you select with jquery
2. you can use `$(this).parent()` function
3. i don't understand last question if you want this value of written text just use `$(this).val()`

hope this what you want!

Comment: 3. Nop. I want to access this  <div class="dropdown-menu">  using $(this). because I want append something

Comment: do you mean I use $(this).parent() when I click a in dropdown-menu can I access UL

Comment: for example
$(this).parent().append('<p>test</p>');

Comment: if you want to access ul 
$(this).parent().prev().prev()

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().prev() working fine but fist one is not working. If I click dropdown-item and i want to access ul in above using $(this). this is not working $(this).parent().

Comment: use $(this).parent().prev().prev() :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149307/discussion-between-knizer-and-ind).

Comment: I want to know when text box keyup I want to access dropdown-menu using $(this). This dropdown-menu is next to text box.